# How to validate access token within Resource Server obtained from the iOS client

Tags: spring-security, federated-identity, spring-security-rest, facebook-java-api

I am building a spring boot java resource server as a backend for an iOS app. The iOS App authenticates users using federated login with Facebook and passes access token for resource server to create an internal user. linked to the facebook profile.

Any documentation I came across discusses how to use spring security to authenticate/authorize users using login form, but I am just trying to parse/validate the access token already given by FB. How can I do this? Google offers [a library](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) to easily parse access token and extract user's information, but I can't find a counterpart library for facebook.

Comment: I don't think I've got the whole picture yet. Why do you need to parse the access token? Typically, the purpose of an access token is to give you access to FB's API. You can use the access token to query FB's API for the data you need.

Comment: At the end of the day, we'd like to offer users to login with their facebook id and retrieve the existing user if the email, or user id matches.

Comment: You can get these information from FB API using the token from user.